# a word / idiom for pulling something closer for a sniff?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is where I am:

"Gliding at a low altitude, his fingers reached for a flower, plucked it and pulled it closer to his nose" / ... to smell"

I'm not looking for anything too exotic, but would still like to hear any idea, to learn

Comment: It would be a heavy flower, if you had to 'pull it' to you. I would say *brought it closer to his nose*.

Comment: To reduce unnecessary redundancy, I think you can/should get rid of either "to smell" (as @WS2 has suggested) OR any reference to "his nose",i.e., "... and brought it close enough to smell." Not an idiom or single word, but "bringing something close enough to smell" is all that I can think of

Comment: @PapaPoule that's why the / slash is there ^

Comment: Ooups! Sorry, my redundo-meter and I totally missed the slash and 2d end-quote! In spite of my blunder re redundancy, "... close enough to smell" might still be a viable option to consider as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drew close? "Gliding at a low altitude, his fingers reached for a flower, plucked it and drew it closer to his nose to smell.

Answer (score 1):

> "Gliding at a low altitude, his fingers reached for a flower, plucked
>   it and pulled it closer to his nose" *to catch its scent*, an olfactory delight.

Answer (score 0):

"Gliding at a low altitude, his fingers reached for a flower, plucked it and pulled it closer, to better savour its intoxicating aroma" ?

Comment: ... "Ah, the rose! How it reminded him of that quaint cottage in Much Wenlock those many years ago. How boundless the world had seemed! How simple! How care-free! Tea with the parson in mother's garden, beneath the arbouretum! Everywhere the smell of rose and chamomile! How can such joy evaporate as if so much dewy morning mist? Where now, is the past, that far-off land? It is here! In this very rose!"

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom for this type of olfactory rapture would be to **drink in its fragrance**, but that does not necessarily imply physically moving the object nearer one's nose.  That said, in your context it would be pretty clear that's what was happening:

> Gliding at a low altitude, his fingers reached for a flower, the better to drink in its intoxicating fragrance.